# Map entities to viewmodels and add specific observables to it with knockout mapping plugin

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

This is code that works but it could be better by using the knockoutjs mapping plugin:

I have 5 domain properties on my entity (e) which I want to wrap with a viewmodel turning the entity properties into observables. Then I want to add another 6th property to each viewmodel which is the isSelected property. All this with the mapping plugin.

```
function activate(){
    var schoolyearModels = dataservice.getSchoolyears();
    var schoolyearViewModels = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < schoolyearModels.length; i++){
        var e = schoolyearModels[i];
        var schoolyearViewModel = new SchoolyearViewModel(e.schoolyearId, 
                                            e.schoolyearName, e.from, e.to, 
                                            e.lastEdited, self.Selected);
        schoolyearViewModels.push(schoolyearViewModel);
    }
    return schoolyears(schoolyearViewModels);
}
```

**Create the ViewModel:**

```
function SchoolyearViewModel(id, schoolyearName, from, to, lastEdited, selected){
    var me = this;
    me.schoolyearId = id;
    me.schoolyearName = ko.observable(schoolyearName);
    me.from = ko.observable(from);
    me.to = ko.observable(to);
    me.lastEdited = ko.observable(lastEdited);
    me.isSelected = ko.computed(function (){
        return selected() === me;
    });
}
```

The data from the server is JSON.

What I tried failed early becasue the viewmodel I get from the mapping plugin makes no sense/it contains not the properties it should...

**Fake JSON server data:**

```
var s1 = { schoolyearId: 1, schoolyearName: 'Schoolyear 1', 
          from: new Date(), to: new Date(), lastEdited: new Date() };
var s2 = { schoolyearId: 2, schoolyearName: 'Schoolyear 2', 
          from: new Date(), to: new Date(), lastEdited: new Date() };
var s3 = { schoolyearId: 3, schoolyearName: 'Schoolyear 3', 
          from: new Date(), to: new Date(), lastEdited: new Date() };
var s4 = { schoolyearId: 4, schoolyearName: 'Schoolyear 4', 
          from: new Date(), to: new Date(), lastEdited: new Date() };
var s5 = { schoolyearId: 5, schoolyearName: 'Schoolyear 5', 
          from: new Date(), to: new Date(), lastEdited: new Date() };
var s6 = { schoolyearId: 6, schoolyearName: 'Schoolyear 6', 
          from: new Date(), to: new Date(), lastEdited: new Date() };
var s7 = { schoolyearId: 7, schoolyearName: 'Schoolyear 7', 
          from: new Date(), to: new Date(), lastEdited: new Date() };
var s8 = { schoolyearId: 8, schoolyearName: 'Schoolyear 8', 
          from: new Date(), to: new Date(), lastEdited: new Date() };
var s9 = { schoolyearId: 9, schoolyearName: 'Schoolyear 9', 
          from: new Date(), to: new Date(), lastEdited: new Date() };

 var schoolyears = [s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9];
 var jsondata = JSON.stringify(schoolyears );
 var viewModelData = ko.mapping.fromJSON(jsondata);
```

When I look now at the viewModelData I expected it to have 5 observable properties but they are not there ?

How do I correctly map my JSON data?

Comment: What do you mean on "expected it to have 5 observable properties but they are not there"? Because the `viewModelData` gets correctly pupulated with the array http://jsfiddle.net/CBhpW/1/

Comment: OK I was confused with some other thing, but fact is the viewModelData has the array with the properties in the _latestValue which is internal and should not be used. At least the underscore is a sign of internal functions. I can enumerate the _latestValue array with viewModelData._latestValue.forEach(function (e) {do stuff}); but then I have to access the internal _latestValue to add my 6th observable property... You see my misery?

Comment: Don't see your misery at all. 1. You don't have to stringify your data. No reason for it. You already have an array, ko.mapping.fromJS(yourArr) should return back with an array with all object properties set to observable. Further more, you don't even need ko.mapping in your case, you already have a client view model. loop through the array, new up the viewmodel and pass your object to get the viewmodel you are creating. I am confused as to what you are trying to get here!

Comment: I was just trying to remove the need calling the function SchoolyearViewModel() by using the mapping plugin and after adding the 6th property to my viewmodel created/returned by the mapping plugin. Is that not a correct approach?

Comment: "... 1. You don't have to stringify your data. No reason for it..." This is a misunderstanding on your side i guess. I just create array data to stringify it because knockout wants json data in the .fromJSON() function only because of that I created the array that I can easily create json... BUT ok when you say the fromJS() accepts also an array then I have to JSON.Parse my json data (from server) and return an array of objects I guess and map this then.

Comment: @nemesv MAYBE this is my problem. When I take your jsfiddle and debug the viewModelData object I can not find anywhere in the object hierarchy the 5 properties/KO-functions. When I bind this object and the binding works why can I not see the ko functions in the viewModelData object? ONLY in the internal _latestValue property which contains an array with the observable ko functions.